# Determining the order of $-a$ if $a$ is a primitive root

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> 1. Let $p$ be a prime such that $p\equiv1\pmod4$. Prove that $a$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ if and only if $-a$ is a primitive root mod $p$.
> 2. Let $p$ be a prime such that $p\equiv3\pmod4$. Prove that $a$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ if and only if $−a$ has order $\dfrac{p−1}{2}$.

For the second one, there is a theorem that says that if the orders of $c$ and $d$ are relatively prime, then the order of $cd$ is the product of the orders of $c$ and $d$.
So, if the order of $-1$ is $2$ and the order of $-a$ is $\dfrac{p−1}{2}$, then the order of $a$ is $p-1$. But, what about the other direction?

Answer (score 1):

If $ord_p(-a)=d\implies (-a)^d\equiv1\pmod p$

Now, $(-a)^d=a^d(-1)^d=\begin{cases}
   \ a^d & \text{if } d\text{ is even} \\
    \ -a^d & \text{if }d \text{ is odd}\ 
  \end{cases}$

If $d$ is even and $ord_p(-a)=ord_p a$ and vice versa

$\implies $ if $-a$ is a primitive root so will be $a$ and vice versa

If $d$ is odd and $(-a)^d\equiv1\pmod p\implies a^d\equiv-1$
$\implies ord_pa$ does not divide $d$ and $a^{2d}\equiv1\pmod p\implies ord_pa=2d $

Comment: thank, what about 1? when p=1mod4?

Comment: @user1932595, if $p\equiv1\pmod 4, p-1=4r$ for some integer $r$ . So, $\frac{p-1}2=2r$ which is even

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is a primitive root, then $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ is -1; it's a square root of 1, so it has to be -1 or 1, but it can't be 1 since $a$ is primitive.

So $(-a)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(a)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=(-1)(-1)=1.$